# Possible ddos attack and exim failing - apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, exim, ddos, fail2ban

We have a dedicated server which one of the sites is gettinga huge amount of traffic and overloading the server.
It seams exim is also getting attacked.

I have kind of inherited this server and im at a loss for what to do.

I installed fail2ban a few days ago and set it up but since then exim and apache have had to be restarted a couple times due to overload.

This server doesnt have any mail accounts on it that I can see either.

Any advice would be appreciated and any links for stuff I should read up on would be handy too.

It is CentOS 6, has WHM/CPanel 11
Apache 2.4

Comment: Use the installed monitoring to gather data and get a feel for what's happening on the system when it gets busy and then apply scientific method.

Comment: Seriously - if you got no clue whatsoever get somebody who has it fast! That's the best thing to do.